# Sand on road cutting grooves in brake rotors

Tags: wheels, brake-rotor, wear

I know someone who has to drive on a sandy road or dirt road everyday.
She drives a van 2015 and has factory rims with 4 cut outs in the rims
for air flow i guess. It was factory made that way. She has to drive on a dirt road
2 miles long everyday before she reaches the main paved road. The sand is 
cutting groves in her front rotors. What can be done about that? I am unsure what to do about it.

Comment: What makes you think it's the sandy road which is doing it? From your description, this is normal wear. Your brakes and rotors are going to be exposed to these elements whether there are slots in the rims or not ... you can just see the wear easier.

Comment: can you provide pictures?